# Dynamic "at" the initial point in an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the initial value problems.

Consider the following dynamic

$$y'(t) = f(t), 0<t \text{ with } y(0) = y_0 \tag 1$$ 
for some smooth function $f$.

Do we implicitly assume that the dynamic **at the initial time** $t=0$ is given by $f(0)$? That is, $y'(0) = f(0)$? In the problem itself, the dynamic is given only for $t>0$, so what happens "at" $t= 0$?

If the function $f(t)$ defined strictly for $t>0$ cannot be extended "nicely" to $f(0)$, would the above IVP be not well-defined?

Comment: Indeed one implicitely assumes that solutions $y$ are continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and have a derivative from the right at $0$, which is $f(0)$. Thus, for every $t\geqslant0$, $$y(t)=y_0+\int_0^tf(s)\,ds.$$